# Deleting a TSX file throws TypeScript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

After deleting any `.tsx` file I see this error:

*TS1208: 'MyFile.tsx' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.*

I've tried restarting VSCode, restarting the TS Server and refreshing the page. Nothing seems to prevent this when deleting any `.tsx` file. The only solution I've found so far is to restart webpack.

Has anyone else run into this? I don't see anything unusual in my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "lib": [ "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext" ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "app/@types"
    ],
    "outDir": "public",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": ["node","jest"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [ "app/*" ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "public",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Does `MyFile.tsx` export anything? Usually this error comes up as a result of the module having no exports.

Comment: It did export the `MyFile` component. I didn't have any problems until I deleted the file. I also verified there were no remaining references to anything from `MyFile.tsx` in any other files after deleting it